# Store textbox changes in database

Tags: sql, database, save

I want to store the values of multiple editable text-boxes in my database. The user can edit them all the time and my question is when to save them? If I execute a SQL statement every time the content changes (in the `onchange event`) there is too much traffic on the database, isn't it? 
Is there any better solution? 
I'd like to do it without a save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the changes periodically (e.g. every 5 seconds), and try sending any unsaved changes upon leaving the page (`beforeunload` event):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
    /* Check for changes and send anything unsaved. */
});
```